# `require': cannot load such file in production (rabl)

Tags: unicorn, production-environment, rabl, digital-ocean, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to deploy my rails app to Digital Ocean and I'm getting this error in Unicorn log

(Please note I'm using `rabl` for my json output)

> require': cannot load such file -- rabl (LoadError)

But if I run this locally in production mode `rails s -e production` it works without complaining

This is my `rabl` config file

```
#config/initializers/rabl_init.rb
require 'rabl'
Rabl.configure do |config|
  config.include_json_root = false
end
```

My Gem file

```
.....
gem "unicorn"
gem 'capistrano'
gem 'rvm-capistrano'

gem 'rabl'
gem 'oj'
```

I'm on

```
ruby 2.0

rails 4.1.5

rabl 0.10.1
```

What would it be I'm doing wrong?

```
oj 2.10.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that , when I restart the

`unicorn`
   `ngnix` it started working, just posting here if anyone come across :)